# How to use fork() in C to run multiple processes that read and write with shared arrays

Tags: c, memory-management, multiprocessing

I'm a relative beginner with C and am dipping my toes into multiprocessing. If this question is pretty basic or is missing necessary details I apologize, but I couldn't find any direct solutions with some google searching.

I have a NxM array of random int values, and an empty 1D array of length N to store results.

I want to create K processes, evenly divide up the N rows of integer values among them, and then have each process sum up the number of odd integers within their assigned rows and write the resulting values to their corresponding locations in the results array. (or any other arbitrary function that returns an integer output).

The arrays can be be of any length and can get pretty large, so I'd like to avoid any unnecessary duplication of memory here.

I understand fork() is used to create multiple processes, but it seems to duplicate the memory space of the parent process as well - is there a way to have each child process access the memory addresses of the parent process without needing additional space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want are threads.
Threads allow multiprocessing without duplicating the address space.
Read about `pthread` online for the most popular way to start threads in c.

Answer (score 0):

A forked process as you noted "duplicates" the memory space, however the memory is not actually duplicated but instead a technique called copy-on-write (COW) is used. With this technique, when a fork occurs, the parent process's pages are not copied for the child process. Instead, the pages are shared between the child and the parent process. Whenever a process (parent or child) modifies a page, a separate copy of that particular page alone is made for that process (parent or child) which performed the modification. This process will then use the newly copied page rather than the shared one in all future references.

As you want to share memory between two processes you need to look at using inter-process communication (IPC) which can be done many ways, such as via pipes/sockets, or mapping a block of shared memory that is shared with the forked process. Child processes inherit the parent's open file descriptors which can be used to setup this channel.

Alternatively if you use threads instead of forking, the threads are running using the same memory space with no copy on write symantecs.

Note that in all cases you have to take care to avoid race conditions with the shared resources or two processes may try to alter the shared ram at the same time corrupting each other.

In most cases you will want threading over forking.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info!

One thing I now realize I left out the original question was that the "arbitrary function" that is performed on each row has the potential to be pretty CPU intensive. As a result, I would like the ability to use multiple processor cores concurrently - is this something that is not allowed with threads?

My understanding was that multithreading involved context-switching on a single core, where multiprocessing was utilizing multiple cores - is that not always the case?

Comment: each thread will be scheduled onto the most suitable available CPU core by the kernel automatically.